# no funciona libreria: leafletjs Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "leaflet" ionic 3?

Tags: ionic, ionic3, ionic-framework

Asi se lo llama desde la pagina principal:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import L from "leaflet";
```

Utilice la referencia a esta pagina :
http://tphangout.com/ionic-3-leaflet-maps-geolocation-markers/

Comment: Hace unos días hice una aplicación utilizando la misma librería y no me dio problemas. Estás seguro que ejecutaste la línea 
npm install leaflet --save ? Es la que hace falta si o si para que la puedas llamar luego. Si no me equivoco no es necesario declararlo en el fichero app.module.ts

Comment: Es posible que te haya dado un error al haberlo instalado, mira a ver si te sale el mensaje run 'npm audit fix', corriendo ese comando lo arreglas

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias tuve que instalar de nuevo y recien funciono, y ahora corre, instale fuera de mi proyecto por eso no reconocia, instale dentro de mi proyecto el siguiente comando:

```
npm install leaflet --save
```

Gracias a todos

Comment: Perfecto! tenía pinta de haberse instalado mal. Cuando puedas (creo que tienen que pasar dos días) marca tu respuesta como correcta para que si alguien tiene el mismo problema encuentre la respuesta rápidamente.

Answer (score 0):

Hola por el error no encuentra la libreria, lo mas posible es que no la hayas instalado.

`npm install -S leaflet`

Comment: instale de esta forma como dice el tutorial:1
 
npm install leaflet --save

Comment: Esta respuesta tiene mas pinta de ser un comentario